# how to specify basic routes with restify

Tags: node.js, routes, restify

The following works

```
server.get('.*', restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': './myPublic',
    'default': 'testPage.html'
}));
```

I can navigate to **http:localhost:8080** and the static page located inside /myPublic is displayed in the browser.

Now i want to change the route so that i can navigate to 
**http:localhost:8080/test**. Therefore i changed the above code to

```
server.get('/test', restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': './myPublic',
    'default': 'testPage.html'
}));
```

Does not work, error is

```
{
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "/test"
}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

I had wrongly assumed a url */test/whatever/path* represents an abstract virtual action (similar to ASP.NET MVC routing), rather than concrete physical files on the server. Not the case with restify.

How restify works is, for static resources, whatever you type on the url, it must exist on disk on the server, starting at the path specified in 'directory'.
So when i request **localhost:8080/test**, i am actually seeking the resource **/myPublic/test/testPage.html** on disk; if i type *localhost:8080/test/otherPage.html*, i am actually seeking the resource */myPublic/test/otherPage.html* on disk.

**The details:**

With the first route

```
server.get('.*', restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': __dirname + '/myPublic',
    'default': 'testPage.html'
}));
```

the RegEx '.*' says match anything! So in the browser i can type 
**localhost:8080/**, **localhost:8080/testPage.html**, **localhost:8080/otherPage.html**, **localhost:8080/whatever/testPage.html**, **localhost:8080/akira/fubuki/**, etc and the GET request will end up being routed to the above handler, and provided the paths */myPublic/testPage.html, /myPublic/otherPage.html, /myPublic/whatever/testpage.html, /myPublic/akira/fubuki/testpage.html*, etc exist on disk, the request will be served.

With the second route

```
server.get('/test', restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': __dirname + '/myPublic',
    'default': 'testPage.html'
}));
```

this handler will match the get request **localhost:8080/test**, and it will serve the default page on disk at **public/test/testPage.html**.

To make the handler more flexible, i could have used a RegEx

```
server.get(/\/test.*\/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': __dirname + '/myPublic',
    'default': 'testPage.html'
}));
```

This RegEx says match '/test' followed by any char (.) 0 or more times (*), followed by a slash(/), followed by any char 0 or more times. Examples could be **localhost:8080/test/**, **localhost:8080/testis/**, **localhost:8080/testicles/**, **localhost:8080/test/otherPage.html**, **localhost:8080/testicles/otherPage.html**, and provided the paths + respective files exist on disk, e.g. */public/test/testPage.html, /public/testis/testPage.html, /public/testicles/otherPage.html*, etc then they would be served to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like restify is looking for a regexp for the route, not a string. Try this:

```
/\/test\//
```

Comment: yes, i tried regex also before posting the question, but it didn't work. I've done further experimentation and will post an answer shortly. In my humble opinion, the concept of routing in restify is broken.